# Is this possible to update the stocks field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is what it looks like in the firestore and I've also set the `colorStocks` to a `Number`

[image]

In a `select`, if the user chose `Shirt2`. They could also set a color they want. This is how I showed this in `select`

[image]

The `value` for each of those selection contains the `id` of the document.

```
const SelectProduct = ({ value, onChange, names }) => {
  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="vaccinator-name">Products</InputLabel>
      <Select value={value} onChange={onChange} fullWidth>
        {names &&
          names.map((index) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={index.id}
              value={index.id}
              // defaultValue={}
            >
              {index.prodName + " " + index.size}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

**Main.js**
To get the available colors, I plan to filter in the `products` array based on `selectedProduct`

```
<SelectProduct
          value={selectedProduct}
          onChange={handleChange}
          names={products}
        />
```

This is the sample code on what the rest of the fields `SelectProducts` and the color looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-order-working-4f6g2

And then onSubmit, the `colorStocks` will also be updated. Would this work this way?

**UPDATE**

I changed it into `red : 50`
[image]

Comment: I’m not sure about the code itself, but I might recommend considering changing the shape of the entry from an array to a mapping. You can remove redundancy and use pairs like “red: 10”.

Comment: @OFRBG I updated the post, is this what you meant?

Comment: @OFRBG if the fields are `red` and `green`, how would I edit the colors if ever they were changed or I could just remove the fields right away?

Comment: Hi @Ravenous Red, could you please clarify what's the specific problem on your question. what specific field do you want to update? and your sample code is not working on submit.

Comment: @Marc Anthony I wanted to update the `red:10` it's like it's the available stocks for the color red. About the codesandbox, it isn't connected to firebase. It was just a sample layout of what the textfields looks like

Comment: Hi @RavenousRed, have you tried any? if so, please include your Firestore query in your question.